# How to copy couple stl lists in one but only with some property

Tags: c++, stl, c++03

I have couple lists of pointers to custom class ( class is simple Person with basic data).
How to copy pointers (shallow copy) from all lists to one new list but only Persons which are from Portland (city==Portland)? I am using list from STL ( list ). I cannot use C++11.

```
class Person{
public:
long id;
string name;
string last_name;
string city

};
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you should use `copy_if` and a lambda:

```
std::list<Person*> src, dst;

std::copy_if(src.cbegin(), src.cend(), std::back_inserter(dst),
             [](Person * p) -> bool { return p->city == "Portland"; });
```

If you have an older platform (which doesn't have lambdas or `copy_if`), you'll have to spell the loop out manually:

```
for (std::list<Person*>::const_iterator it = src.begin(), e = src.end(); it != e; ++it)
{
    if ((*it)->city == "Portland") { dst.push_back(*it); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example in C++03.

```
struct PersonComparerByCity : public std::unary_function<Person*, bool>
{
   PersonComparerByCity(const std::string& c):city(c) { }
   result_type operator() (argument_type arg) const 
   { return arg && arg->city == city; }
private:
   std::string city;
};

std::list<Person*> p;
std::list<Person*> result;
std::remove_copy_if(p.begin(), p.end(), std::back_inserter(result), 
std::not1(PersonComparerByCity("Portland")));
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/a8e36e63b1f9924281768d90f7a090da